# angular 2 ngIf with observable?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript, observable

I have a very simple service and its job is to get either 200 or 401 from api/authenticate url.

> auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.authenitcationEnpoint)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(response: Response) {
        let body = response;
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

now I want to use this in my html I know I can create a subscriber and based on response or error code set a variable but my problem is I will have to duplicate the code all over the place. I want very simple

```
<div *ngIf="authService.AuthenticateUser()">my content</div>
```

If its 401 which is coming from handleError then hide otherwise show the div.

Its like getting boolean value from Observable. I also have AuthGuard.

> authguard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    private isActive: boolean = true;
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        this.authService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(() => {},
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0) {
                    let link = ['contactus'];
                    this.router.navigate(link);
                    this.isActive = false;
                }
            });
        return this.isActive;
    }   

}
```

I cannot use authGuard.canActive() as well in ngIf. Is there any easier way to do it without duplicating code. I am pretty sure AuthGuard is not working as it must return true everytime because subscribe will take time.

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    private isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,private authGuard: AuthGuard) {
        this.authService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response.status == 200)
                    this.isAuthenticated = true;
            },
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0)
                    this.isAuthenticated = false;
            });
    }
}
```

> home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService, private utilityService: UtilityService, private homeService: HomeService, private factoryService: FactoryService, private supplierService: SupplierService, private businessAreaService: BusinessAreaService, private router: Router) {
        this.authService.authenticateUser()
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response.status == 200)
                    this.isAuthenticated = true;
            },
            error => {
                if (error.indexOf("401") >= 0)
                    this.isAuthenticated = false;
            });
        this.customData = new CustomData(http);
    }
}
```

As you can see alot of duplicated code. I am trying to avoid duplication.

When I call my api a pop up appears to enter windows username/password for windows Authentication. I dont get 401 until I cancel that pop up. so I want to hide my menu + home component.

In my service I get response:200 in **map**
and unauthorized:401 in **catch** block

Comment: Where is this ngIf coming from ? A component I assume ? It would be nice to have the `.ts` of that component.

Comment: And if you don't `subscribe` to an observable, you'll never have any result.

Comment: Finally, once you have a component that fetches the result of an http call (from a service), you can either subscribe to it and save the value to display it into your view OR use the `async` pipe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, you are returning an observable and not the value:

```
authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(AppSettings.authenitcationEnpoint)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

What you should do is create a property in your service and then use this property in your html and not the function that subscribes to the observable. Something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    isAuthenticated: boolean = false; //The variable

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.authenitcationEnpoint)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(response: Response) {
        let body = response;
        this.isAuthenticated = body.isAuthenticated; //here you assign a value to variable
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

And then, in your html, just use:

```
<div *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated">my content</div>
```

Another way of doing this is using the `async` pipe. So, the view will wait the observation to return before make digest cicle. Something like:

```
<div *ngIf="authService.AuthenticateUser() | async">my content</div> // Here you use the async pipe
```

Comment: Because if the value changes, it won't be updated. It's the main interest with observable.

Comment: @Maxime It won't be updated? Why are you saying this?

Comment: Arf it's not what I meant exactly my bad. He won't be able to subscribe to the change of that value. With is too bad in this case and in general. If he has an observable he should keep it :)

Comment: this is good suggestion but 401 will go to catch block, so should I make it false in catch and true in case it goes to map?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. If you look at the declaration level, the variable is false for default. So, only when you have a ´200/201´ status code you will need to change the variable to true. If the ´401´ is returned, the variable is already false, so you don't need to do anything in ´catch()´. I've assumed that you can authenticate only when you are not authenticated. ANother thing is that this service should be a singleton, so the variable is assigned only once. Put the service loader in app provider level, not in a child module...

Comment: I didnt use the variable but async pipe helped me ta