# ngif stays false, even though its value is right

Tags: html, angular, typescript, redux, store

My code looks like this:

component.ts

```
export class ViewScaleComponent implements OnInit {
    private range$: Observable<number>;
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.range$ = this.store.select(x => x.view.range);
    }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="(range$ | async)">
  here {{ range$ | async }}
</div>
```

The div remains commented in the DOM, an Angular Ghost.

If I remove `ngif`, the `div` appears, but the data interpolation fetches nothing (only here and the following whitespace appears).

If in `ngOnInit()` I do:

```
this.range$ = this.store.select(x => x.view.range).do(x => console.log(x));
console.log("on init " + this.range$);
```

then I get:

```
on init [object Object]
undefined
21
```

where the last two console logs come from the same line (`do()`). I wonder whether the first `undefined` is the reason for not displaying the `di`.

It's worth noting that *sometimes* it works(I see the `div` and the values of`range$` are being updated as expected).

Any ideas?

PS: I read [angular 2 ngIf with observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977839/angular-2-ngif-with-observable), but the observable and `async` combination look pretty similar to mine.

Comment: Please post correct syntax. I see here `*ngif="range$ | async)"` at least two mistakes

Comment: It would be easy to help you if you provided a minimal reproduction

Comment: I tried with Plunker @yurzui, but I had a difficult time to simulate the store serving the data. I should note that I am beginner.

Comment: I can help you, just add your code to plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CeoF3g2aTmasGZppQ9CC and click `Fork`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the `ngIf` for this just put  `{{ range$ | async}}`

**Update**

```
range:any ;
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(x => x.view.range).subscribe(x => this.range = x);
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngif="range">
  here {{ range }}
</div>
```

Comment: If I don't use `ngif`, the `div` will appear, but the data interpolation will be empty. Also, in your answer, what is `range`?

Comment: the range you get from the component , if you dont want the div to appear use `ng-container`

Comment: See my updated answer. But I have an observable `range$` there only. Hmm, what do you mean with the ng container? I am a beginner, could you provide an example please?

Comment: the range is a observable and using the async filters turns it into a hot observable so that it can emit data , or if you are confused you could subscribe to the store and get the data that will be better as you mentioned you are a beginner and you should take small steps . More on [ngcontainer](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer)

Comment: I think I follow the concept Rahul, but I don't see it working, and I can't figure out why. If I do what you mention in your answer, I will only see "here ", meaning that the data interpolation did not succeeded. Moreover, since I only have `range$` in my class, shouldn't I use `range$` in my template too? And I just replaced `div` with `ng-container`, but the behavior was the same.

Comment: ohh sorry i completely forgot the variable it should be `range$` instead of `range` my bad

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no luck again :/

Comment: this should have @gsamaras. I would say just try a hello world or guess some thing is broken in the app. can you create a stack blitz demo kind of this issue

Comment: I had tried before with Plunker too, but I am having a difficult time simulating the store, etc. BTW, I updated my question with another observation that might help!